# Multinesting Gradle Projects in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using IntelliJ Idea 14.1.4 and Gradle, and I am trying to create sub projects and nested sub projects:

```
Project
|--Research
|--Development
   |--Algorithms
```

The reason for this is that research algorithms are separate from the development implementation. They are written in different languages (Python vs. Java) and used by different programmers, however I still want to maintain one Gradle project, so eventually researchers would be able to use stable existing algorithms implementations when developing new ones.

My problem is that Idea doesn't recognize properly the Gradle structure of the second level Gradle sub project: **Project** is recognized well, **Research** and **Development** are recognized well, but the **Algorithms** sub project is not recognized:
The code inspection of the **gradle.build** file in **Algorithms** project is highlighted as a warning with a message that *test cannot be applies to Groovy.lang.closure* Note that below is the complete **build.gradle**:

```
test{
  useTestNG()
  testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

Also, when I try in Idea **Run->Edit Configurations->Defaults->Gradle** and trying to choose Gradle project, I see that in the pop-up menu **Development** and **Research** do appear as sub-projects of **Project**, but **Algorithms** appears as a stand alone project.
Making the project however does create all the binaries and manually running a test case also works well.

When I run Gradle for command line, it appears to be working well and recognizing all nested projects: All the code is being compiled and tests are being ran. 
So the question here is if there is an Idea issue here which is not working correctly with Gradle, or am I doing something wrong?

Code for **build.gradle** inside **Project**:

```
allprojects {
  group 'com.project'
  version 'v0.1'
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

Code for **settings.gradle** inside **Project**

```
rootProject.name = 'Project'
include 'Development'
include 'Development:Algorithms'
include 'Research'
```

Code for **build.gradle** of **Development** sub-project:

```
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies{
    testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.4'
  }
}
```

Other code samples that I might be writing wrong (most of them are auto generated by Idea:

**Project.iml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id="Project"      external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="com.project" external.system.module.version="v0.1" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

**Development.iml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":Development" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/.." external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="com.project" external.system.module.version="v0.1" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
</module>
```

**Algorithms.iml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id=":Development:Algorithms" external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$/../.." external.system.id="GRADLE" external.system.module.group="com.project" external.system.module.version="v0.1" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/main" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/test" />
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" type="java-resource" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" type="java-test-resource" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="module-library" scope="TEST">
      <library>
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/plugins/testng/lib/testng.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </orderEntry>
  </component>
</module>
```

I would like to point the following:

- All projects and sub-projects have the same group: **com.project**
- In **Algorithms.iml** the original (auto generated) value of **external.linked.project.id** was **:Algorithms**. I have tried setting it to **:Development:Algorithms** to see if it will change anything. After each change I have ran rebuild.
- In **Algorithms.iml** the original (auto generated) value of **external.root.project.path** was **$MODULE_DIR$/..**. I have tried setting it to **$MODULE_DIR$/../..** to see if it will change anything. After each change I have ran rebuild.

****************************Edit********************************

Further investigation shows an issue with the *workspace.xml* file:
There is a **GradleLocalSettingsElement** there that was automatically created, but appears to be wrong: There are two different entries: one for Development and Devlopment:Algorithms and onw for the rest, so I might have did something wrong when I created the project.
My question is if there is a reference for the structure of this file and specifically for the elements inserted by the Gradle plugin?

```
<map>
  <entry>
    <key>
      <ExternalProjectPojo>
        <option name="name" value="Development" />
        <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/Development" />
      </ExternalProjectPojo>
    </key>
    <value>
      <list>
        <ExternalProjectPojo>
          <option name="name" value="Development" />
          <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/Development" />
        </ExternalProjectPojo>
        <ExternalProjectPojo>
          <option name="name" value=":Development:Algorithms" />
          <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/Development/Algorithms" />
        </ExternalProjectPojo>
      </list>
    </value>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <key>
      <ExternalProjectPojo>
        <option name="name" value="Project" />
        <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
      </ExternalProjectPojo>
    </key>
    <value>
      <list>
        <ExternalProjectPojo>
          <option name="name" value="Project" />
          <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        </ExternalProjectPojo>
        <ExternalProjectPojo>
          <option name="name" value=":Development" />
          <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/Development" />
        </ExternalProjectPojo>
        <ExternalProjectPojo>
          <option name="name" value=":Research" />
          <option name="path" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/Research" />
        </ExternalProjectPojo>
      </list>
    </value>
  </entry>
</map>
```